# Get currently open document and page in view for Adobe Reader instance

Tags: interprocess, adobe-reader

My app needs to know what is the document currently opened in adobe reader, and what is the current page in view. Is it possible to find that out?

My app is .net application, an runs with admin privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using [Adobe IAC](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/interapplication_communication.html) which on Windows is basically COM.

From what I gather you need to call [`GetActiveDoc ()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.6.html) on the Reader instance and then call [`GetAVPageView()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.38.html) on the result and then call [`GetPageNum()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.65.html).